# Add Prefix to auto-increment in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I have my database with table test1.
It has a primary id "Id" which is auto-increment.
Now the id is in the format 1,2,3.. . .Is it possible to store the primary Id as
PNR1,PNR2,PNR3 .. . . and so on(with auto-increment).

Comment: The answers on this questions are VERY UNHELPFUL!  I did find much more help on this Q&A over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix for anyone looking to do this or similar!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Either add the prefix in the query, or use a view instead.

Comment: @ IVA - Thanks for the reply. Wil do this

Answer (score 4):

Not really, but you can use another column (but a view)
this is already covered here:
[MySQL Auto Increment Custom Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228408/mysql-auto-increment-custom-values)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it if you have INT prefix. You have id as INT in table

```
 // START PREFIX
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `table_name` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); 
  // GET THE LAST ID MAKE SURE IN TABLE YOU 9991

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $lastId =  $row->id;
  }

  list($prefix,$Id) = explode('999',$lastId );
  $Id = ($Id+1);
  $new_id = '999'.$Id;
  // END PREFIX



$insertQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` SET id = '".$new_id."',...");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, I made it work in this way :**

Products Table (products):

```
id_prod(varchar(11), NOT NULL, PK), name(varchar(40))
```

Products Sequence Table (productidseq):

```
id(AI, PK, NOT NULL)
```

Before Insert Trigger in Products Table:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `dbname`.`products_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `products` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into productidseq (id) values(NULL);
set new.id_prod = concat('PROD or any prefix here',last_insert_id());
set @productId = new.id_prod; -- To use outside of trigger this variable is useful.
END
```

When you run below query :

```
insert into products (name) values('Bat');
```

data inside tables will we be like this :

products:

```
id | name
---|-----
 1 | Bat
```

productidseq:

```
id 
---
 1
```

If any better way than this or any cons with this, please comment below. Thanks.