# How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have table like this

```
table
id Varchar(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
```

I want to increment my id field like `'LHPL001','LHPL002','LHPL003'`... etc.
What should I have to do for that? Please let me know any possible way.

Comment: simply add another column to do this.  it's totally normal to have "different kinds" of ID fields in a database.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If you really need this you can achieve your goal with help of separate table for sequencing (if you don't mind) and a trigger.

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0', name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Now the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('LHPL', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you just insert rows to table1

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) 
VALUES ('Jhon'), ('Mark');
```

And you'll have

```
|      ID | NAME |
------------------
| LHPL001 | Jhon |
| LHPL002 | Mark |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ed88/1)** demo

Comment: Is the statement within the trigger atomic? I.e. is it possible that between the INSERT and SET another thread/request inserts into table1_seq causing LAST_INSERT_ID() to return the id of the other request and not the one that was inserted within the BEGIN/END.

Comment: @peterm, I have a doubt trigger part. I changed SET NEW.id = CONCAT('A', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, '500')); because I need my id start from 5001 so I set 500. So I am getting output A5001 which is correct. My doubt is once id reached 5999 then what will be the next id? Is it 6000?

Comment: I tried my self after adding the records in the database I added more than 1000 records and after 5999 my id value starts from V1000 which is totally wrong. I need it should be continued 6000,6001,6002 and so on. any idea in this?

Answer (score 23):

Create a table with a normal numeric auto_increment ID, but either define it with `ZEROFILL`, or use `LPAD` to add zeroes when selecting. Then `CONCAT` the values to get your intended behavior. Example #1:

```
create table so (
 id int(3) unsigned zerofill not null auto_increment primary key,
 name varchar(30) not null
);

insert into so set name = 'John';
insert into so set name = 'Mark';

select concat('LHPL', id) as id, name from so;
+---------+------+
| id      | name |
+---------+------+
| LHPL001 | John |
| LHPL002 | Mark |
+---------+------+
```

Example #2:

```
create table so (
 id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
 name varchar(30) not null
);

insert into so set name = 'John';
insert into so set name = 'Mark';

select concat('LHPL', LPAD(id, 3, 0)) as id, name from so;
+---------+------+
| id      | name |
+---------+------+
| LHPL001 | John |
| LHPL002 | Mark |
+---------+------+
```

Comment: Initially I was thinking of storing the LHPL as a separate column then concat it by concat(col1,col2) but then it will be a pain in the S when someday I need to change the LHPL. So I guess I will be doing it in the program server side.

Answer (score 6):

I know it is late but I just want to share on what I have done for this. I'm not allowed to add another table or trigger so I need to generate it in a single query upon insert. For your case, can you try this query.

```
CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE(
IDNUMBER VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ENAME VARCHAR(30) not null
);
```

Perform a select and use this select query and save to the parameter @IDNUMBER

```
(SELECT IFNULL
     (CONCAT('LHPL',LPAD(
       (SUBSTRING_INDEX
        (MAX(`IDNUMBER`), 'LHPL',-1) + 1), 5, '0')), 'LHPL001')
    AS 'IDNUMBER' FROM YOURTABLE ORDER BY `IDNUMBER` ASC)
```

And then Insert query will be :

```
INSERT INTO YOURTABLE(IDNUMBER, ENAME) VALUES 
(@IDNUMBER, 'EMPLOYEE NAME');
```

The result will be the same as the other answer but the difference is, you will not need to create another table or trigger. I hope that I can help someone that have a same case as mine.

Answer (score -1):

Here is PostgreSQL example without trigger if someone need it on PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE messages_seq;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
    id CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('message_' || nextval('messages_seq')),
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
);

ALTER SEQUENCE messages_seq OWNED BY messages.id;
```