# How to create a unique autoincrement field with a string prefix?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table 'user' with 3 items.

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`customernumber` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`type` enum('customer','admin') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

How can I increment 'customernumber' with the first two letters of the 'type'?

For example, user with ID=10 and type='admin' will have a customernumber 'AD000010'. And user with ID = 12 and type = 'customer' will have a customernumber 'CU000012'?

Is this possible to do this in MySQL without using a trigger? If not, how can I do this with a trigger?

Comment: No, you need a trigger for that.

Comment: Why do you need to store this in a single column? They're two discrete pieces of data. Store them in separate columns and concatenate them when you extract them from the database, if you require that.

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is store the key as two columns. A char prefix and an auto-incrementing int, both of which are grouped for the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE myItems (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    prefix CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, prefix),
    ...
```

Please refer to this link 
[How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-suffix)
hope this help you .