# i want to create a mysql trigger to create primary key as varchar autoincrement

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `org_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `login_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_no` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `android_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `activation_status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `pin` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `imei` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `booth_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `Assignment_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: varchar and autoincrement?? what's the link??  How?

Comment: what do you want to achieve by this.

Answer (score 0):

(Borrowing from [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-suffix))

Assuming you already have your user table created, you can write a [trigger](http://www.sitepoint.com/action-automation-with-mysql-triggers/) to generate the id for you automatically. You'll need a dummy table to hold id's auto-generated by MySQL, allowing the trigger can easily pull new, unique ID's from.

The **Dummy (Sequence) Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE user_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

The **Trigger**:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_user_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I used this to handle a case where I had to generate some seed data for an existing schema (e.g. I could not change the schema). **Please note I'm using this in a dev environment** - no idea how performant or otherwise production-worthy something like this would be. Hopefully a competent dba can provide more insight - but since the question stands, I had a similar issue, and couldn't find an alternative, hopefully this will help someone else...