# php and mysql prefix auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I'm making a website using php and mysql and I want to create an auto increment ID for a table like this:

```
cl.001 , cl.002, dl.001 , dl.002 ... dl.010
```

The prefix is generated by a php function. I thought of this solution but I couldn't make it work:

```
$query='insert into table(reference) values (' . prefix() . ');'
```

I made an auto increment id (int), then a trigger :

```
TRIGGER `referenceTrig` AFTER INSERT ON `individu` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE individu SET REFERENCE = CONCAT(REFERENCE,NEW.id) where id=NEW.id
```

But this also didn't work, I also thought of and 'instead of' trigger but it doesn't exist in mysql.

Comment: Every newbie asks this question. You do not want to do this.

Comment: Depending on the database engine you're using, MySQL can do this automagically for you if you set a composite primary key; but it's rarely sensible to do so

Comment: You might wanna check this link for the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix