# How to increment a default value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a field (demo_field)(varchar) in mysql table. I want to increment this field value with a pre defined prefix.
For example my field first value is `demo001`. Now when ever new values inserted I want to increment the numeric numbers like `demo002, demo003`.
How can I do this with PHP.

Comment: Add `AUTO_INCREMENT` in mysql and omit that field in PHP `insert`

Comment: How to do that? For that we need to set one default value right? I need alpha characters also. If we give auto_increment we can't add alpha characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this -

```
//fetch data from table
$sql = $mysqli->query('select count(demo_field) as total,demo_field from tablename limit 1');
$res = $sql->fetch_assoc();

//generate string from existing data
$str = substr($res['demo_field'], 0, 4);
$dig = str_replace($str, '', $res['demo_field']);
$dig = $dig+$res['total'];

//add padding if needed
$dig = str_pad($dig, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

//concatenate string & digits
$newStr = $str.$dig;

var_dump($newStr);
```

Another way without count

```
$sql = $mysqli->query('select max(demo_field) as demo_field from demo');
$res = $sql->fetch_assoc();

$str = substr($res['demo_field'], 0, 4);
$dig = str_replace($str, '', $res['demo_field']);
$dig += 1;
$dig = str_pad($dig, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$newStr = $str.$dig;

var_dump($newStr);
```

hope this might solve the problem with `count`.

another solution with max count for alphanumeric string and without padding -

```
$sql = $mysqli->query('select max(cast(substring(demo_field, 5) as unsigned)) as digit,     demo_field from demo');
$res = $sql->fetch_assoc();

$str = substr($res['demo_field'], 0, 4);
$dig = $res['digit'] + 1;
$newStr = $str.$dig;

var_dump($newStr);
```

Comment: Yes. Currently I use this method. I just wanted to know whether can directly (some how) increment the value when inserting. Thanks @sgt

Comment: how would you increment a string without string manipulation in php?

Comment: Also there is a small disadvantage on this. taking count for generating number is not a good idea. Because if we delete few values, then generating number according to count may create duplicate values

Comment: yes that would be a problem..then you should prefer doing this with sql rather than php.

Comment: Ok. So no other way? Right. Thanks for your efforts @sgt

Comment: updated my answer.check it out.but it will work only if the increment is in order and not updated manually as it will find max of string field.

Comment: Thanks @sgt. Just one doubt. Will max() work for values with alpha prefix. MAX() is for numeric values right?

Comment: will work but for but it checks like letter by letter and compares them.for this `demo005` will be greater than `demo0010`. and one thing if you dont need padding then dont use it, it will create problem for larger numbers.

Comment: added another solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
//use PHP not mysql
$pre = 'demo';
$num = 0;
define('MAX', 100);
for($num = 0; $num < MAX; $num++)
{
    $pre_str = $pre . sprintf("%03d", $num);
    //insert here
}
```

Comment: Hi, This method can not be used. We have to check already exist values in table, and then increment

Comment: ...i don't know what you want to do then-.-

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an INT field
and translate it to whatever format you want at "select" time.

In MySQL we cannot use AutoIncrement for Varchar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17894239/ and inside this same page http://stackoverflow.com/a/26728953/