# Auto increment that starts with characters in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am having an auto increment in assigning ID. The ID assigned starts from 1 and so on. I want to have an ID that starts with characters, in PHPMYADMIN.

Example for students, ST-0001; for teachers, TE-0001.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this i hope it will work :**

The idea in database design, is to keep each data element separate. And each element has its own datatype, constraints and rules. That `ST0001` is not one field, but two. Same with `XXnnnn` or whatever. It is incorrect , and it will severely limit your ability to use the data, and use database features and facilities.

```
Break it up into two discrete data items:

column_1  VARCHAR(2)

column_2   INTEGER

Then set AUTOINCREMENT on column_2
```

And yes, your Primary Key can be (column_1, column_2), so you have not lost whatever meaning `ST0001` has for you.

Comment: But you can't to get both `ST-1` and `TE-1`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get both ST-1 and TE-1, you must use a sequence table for both student and teacher, with only a AUTOINCREMENT on each table.

When you create a student, insert a row in the student_sequence, get the generated value, and then insert datas into the student table, including the Id value.
For further security, add a foreign key constraint between the student ID and student_sequence ID. 
Same for the teacher.

A variant :
http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/