# Formatted Auto Increment Start from 1 Every Month

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table that its PK format is like this

```
YYMMXXXXXX
```

where `YY` is year in two digits, `MM` is month in two digits and `XXXXXX` is six digit auto increment number that start from 1 if the month change.

Can MySQL do this automatically?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searching solution that using `triggers` but it is use a temporary table.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17894239/1525199

But then I find my own solution:

let say my table name `my_table` and has PK `id (INT)` and also a field `time (datetime)`. I just need to get last (biggest) id in current month from `my_table` then add by 1.

```
SET @mos= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table WHERE MONTH(`time`) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(`time`) = YEAR(NOW()));

SELECT IF(
    @mos IS NULL,
    CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),'000001'),
    @mos + 1
    );
```