# How do i generate unique numbers that isnt already stored in the DB(millions of records)

Tags: php

Is it possible to generate numbers that are 100% unique in a db with millions of records(+ growing)? How?

Comment: INT + AUTO INCREMENT + PRIMARY KEY ? Not sure what database you are using but it should work for most of them.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Answer (score 0):

You could either make the numbers auto-incrementing so that every number is guaranteed to be unique, or you could create a random number, check to see if it exists, and if it does, create another random number, and then repeat this process until one doesn't exist.