# How to retrieve particular data of a row based on its id in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, database

I would like to know how to retrieve the title of a row based on its id.

Its for href link based of next and previous buttons. The id will be determined by

> current id-1= previous id ($pid) and current id+1=next id ($nid)

I have `$nid` and `$pid`, but now i want to get the title of that respective id in the database. Now i am getting only the current id title displayed in the url..

```
href="features/headlines/<?php echo $pid; ?>/<?php echo $title; ?>"
```

i want the `$title` to show the title corresponding to the `$pid` but now i am only getting the title of the current id.

I tried `<?php echo $pid[title]; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

It would be something to the effect of:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$current_id = 6; // Whatever your current ID is here..

// Notice the subtraction from $current_id
$query = "SELECT `title` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '".($current_id-1)."'";
// Would output:
// SELECT `title` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '5'

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$previous_title = $row['title'];

?>
```

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a normalized database schema. This is good! (unless you are talking about some abstract data type in PHP)

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need a special sort of "key" on your column, specifically the primary key with the attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT`

[How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

MySQL can solve any selection based on its id in `O(logn)` time using a simple `BTREE` index. `Primary keys` are keys that basically are a unique representation of each row (in this case, the id is the represenation of title). You would do a query like this:

`SELECT id, title from table_1 WHERE id = '$id_to_select'`

To parse the return result, you have an array of choices:
`mysqli_fetch_row`
`mysqli_fetch_array()`
`mysqli_fetch_assoc`

I think the best one is `mysqli_fetch_array` since you can specify how to fetch the returning row: `MYSQLI_NUM` denotes the index, `MYSQLI_ASSOC` denotes an associative return.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
//Array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'lorem ipsum'
)
```