# how to create unique auto number with php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having some problem with the website I'm creating.  I need to create a tracking number like this **ABC-0001-15**.

- The ABC will depend on the department
- The 0001 is an incremental from the database
- and 15 is the year

I want it to go back to 0001 if the year changes.

How can I achieve this ? I've done my research but I can't find how to, or I don't know the keyword to use.

I found this article on this site
[How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

but I need the user of the website to see the auto-number

Comment: I am not totally sure if I understand your question correctly, but lets see, in my opinion, saving a key like that would be best to be done with multiple columns(i.e. ABC goes in department, 0001 goes in dep_version and 15 goes in year). Then you have a transaction to your system like: select max(dep_version) from table where department = ABC; increment dep_version by 1, and store it with the rest of your data.

Comment: Plus you could make all 3 columns primary key for consistency.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed your English issues and clarified the question.  Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create an empty record, then get its id and update it afterwards... if need be?