# How to use SET and INSERT in one php variable?

Tags: php, mysql

This is not duplicated question, since I am asking how to use SET and INSERT in one PHP variable, there no any questions about AUTO_INCREMENT...

I have below page:

```
<?php

function genWO(){
    $dbtype = "MySQL";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $hostname = "10.10.10.10";
    $dbname = "TABLES";
    //connection to the database
    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $insertNewWONum = "SET @MAX_WO = (SELECT max(WO_NUM) + 1 from GENERIC_TABLES.WO_NUMBERS); INSERT INTO GENERIC_TABLES.WO_NUMBERS (WO_NUM, WO_REQUESTOR) values (@MAX_WO, `test`)";

    if ($conn->query($insertNewWONum) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully". "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $insertNewWONum . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $getWONum = "SELECT LPAD(max(WO_NUM) ,6,0) as NEW_WO_NUM from GENERIC_TABLES.WO_NUMBERS";
    $result = $conn->query($getWONum);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "New WO Number: " . $row["NEW_WO_NUM"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    //close the connection
    $conn->close();
    }

    ?>
```

Since it is not allowed to use INSERT and SELECT for the same table in one query, I am trying to set variable and use it in INSERT query:

```
$insertNewWONum = "SET @MAX_WO = (SELECT max(WO_NUM) + 1 from GENERIC_TABLES.WO_NUMBERS); INSERT INTO GENERIC_TABLES.WO_NUMBERS (WO_NUM, WO_REQUESTOR) values (@MAX_WO, `test`)";
```

But it doesnt work, though it works fine if I am using this query in terminal.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve it please?

Comment: are you perhaps looking for AUTO_INCREMENT ?

Comment: you sure don't want to do it the way you are. See what @e4c5 said

Comment: Your **MySQL** is vulnerable.Learn to use [**`Prepared Statements`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in order to secure your code.

Comment: No, it is not auto increment.. It is just an example.

Comment: It is not duplicated question, I couldnt fine similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since it is not allowed to use INSERT and SELECT for the same table in one query

All issues with your approach aside **of course you can** use `INSERT` and `SELECT` in one statement

```sql
INSERT INTO WO_NUMBERS (WO_NUM, WO_REQUESTOR)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(WO_NUM), 0) + 1, 'Test'
  FROM WO_NUMBERS;
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3204/1) demo.

Now what you need to realize is that your approach is **unsafe for concurrent access**. If this code is executed from two or more sessions simultaneously some or all of them may generate the same number effectively breaking your application.

Use `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead.

```sql
CREATE TABLE WO_NUMBERS
(
  WO_NUM INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  WO_REQUESTOR VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO WO_NUMBERS (WO_REQUESTOR) VALUES ('Test');
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0314/1) demo.

If for some reason you can't use `AUTO_INCREMENT` directly (and I honestly don't see why you couldn't) i.e. you need to add prefixes or augment the generated id/code in some way you can look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17894239/1920232).