# Yearly auto increment reset

Tags: mysql

I have database of service requests and I want to make things clearly sorted.

Currently I have just auto-increment enabled but,
I want to make auto increment of id in this format : xxxx-16,

where 16 is last 2 digits of current year and x are auto incremented id.

is there any way of doing this?

Comment: See here if you really need this in a single field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Comment: thank you very much, really helped me out