# Define Prefix for Auto Increment in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have the `string` like this: `POyyyymm0000`

At the current time: when i am inputting, it will be `PO2017070001`

And i input again it will be `PO2017070002`

And in the next month it will be `PO2017080001`

The question is how to insert **`PO[thecurrentyear][thecurrentmonth][autoincrement, start from 0000 to 9999]`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: use triggers as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **date()** and **rand()** to achieve this
Just like this

```
$id='PO'.date('Ymd').rand(0000,9999);
```

It will produce output as

[image]

**Modified:-**
For unique key you can use **time()** like this

```
$id='PO'.date('Ymd').time(); //o/p is "PO201707061499326403"
```

It will never repeat the same id.

Comment: It's not technically auto-incrementing the final 4 digits this way.

Comment: you are not storing the previous no. any where then how can you get the next no. in auto increment .Actually what you want ?  to make it unique or any thing else ?

Comment: It's not my question :) I'd be happy with a normal digit ID personally. There is another option here though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Comment: But i want (in the next month) or (in the next year) the autoincreement reset to 0000

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn just try my modified answer it will help you.