# I want to autogenerate a primary key

Tags: mysql

I want to autogenerate a primary key of table 1 with prefix using an attribute from table 2, for example if my primary key is autoincremented like 00001, it should take prefix from table 2 and generate the primary key(table 1) or id as GHY00001 with the help of mysql

Answer (score 0):

There is already a question similar to this that was answered brilliantly.

[How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)