# Modify mysql tp add prefix and to be autoincremented to mysql field

Tags: mysql

Is there a option to alter my table to gather the required functionality ?

My Table has id(int), pal_id(varchar,50) ...
At this time id is autoincremented as unique and key, but i need also to make pal_id to be auto incremented, but the field values has a prefix ex: PAL0001

I have tried the solution from [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix) but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: There are a number of usable answers on the question you linked. What did you try, and how did it not work?

Comment: A `view` might be a better choice.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 5.7 you could create a calculated column.

Comment: @Barmar "The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute cannot be used in a generated column definition." :-(