# How to create a Manual Insert ID while adding a new row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to add new rows in my mysql table using PDO object, but it is giving me automated insert ID.

I need to make primary key values like -

```
key_1, key_2, key_3... etc.
```

But for now it's giving me the primary key value as 1,2,3..

Please suggest me some help , thank you.

Comment: Don't bother.  Use the auto-incremented value as the primary key and be happy that MySQL provides this functionality.

Comment: Use AUTO_INCREMENT and add the "key_" prefix in your application layer (if necessary).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Comment: What's the need for this? Primary key values are internal to the database and application and should not be visible to the outside world. Their format is of no consequence. As long as they are unique, you are good. Now, if you still need an ID with a specific format, then this is probably NOT the primary key, but a secondary ID for communications or other purpose.