# auto increase a MySQL registry

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database with 15 records
Example:

```
--------table---------
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
P000112018082800.00A |
```

after P0001 the last number I would like it to be autoincrementable so that from a result to this.

```
P0001
P0002
P0003
P0004
P0005
P0006
P0007
P0008
P0009
P0010
P0011
P0012
P0013
P0014
P0015
```

So the result has to be this

-----------table finish------------

```
    P000112018082800.00A
    P000212018082800.00A
    P000312018082800.00A
    P000412018082800.00A
    P000512018082800.00A
    P000612018082800.00A
    P000712018082800.00A
    P000812018082800.00A
    P000912018082800.00A
    P001012018082800.00A
    P001112018082800.00A
    P001212018082800.00A
    P001312018082800.00A
    P001412018082800.00A
    P001512018082800.00A
```

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Comment: Without additional appendages, It can be incremented; but i doubt it can be **auto**incremented. That requires numeric columns