# How to auto increment for varchar in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

It is possible to increment numbers automatically in MySQL. Is there any way to increment for varchar in MYSQL, example "SL00001" it will increment to "SL00002"?

Comment: question.  is SL00001 the latest record? or are we doing the row_number() function on it?

Comment: Just use a numeric `id` value and `SELECT CONCAT('SL', LPAD(id, 5, '0')) AS id`

Comment: maybe able to use [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) on the numeric `id` to transform it and make it look like a real column. Auto_increment columns are a integer type only.

Comment: @danblack Generated column cannot refer to autoincremented field.

Comment: ack, had a feeling that may be a constraint. Thanks.

Comment: You can use composite primary key for this purpose after adding 2 columns, one for integer and other for varchar. This way you can get a clear user view as well as can reduce code cumbersome in your back-end code as well.

Comment: this might help you. [MySql AutoIncrement ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it automatically using MyISAM engine and appliing [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick)'s comment "Just use a numeric id value and `SELECT CONCAT('SL', LPAD(id, 5, '0')) AS id`":

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (prefix CHAR(2),
>                    num INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>                    PRIMARY KEY (prefix, num),
>                    val INT) ENGINE = MyISAM;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test (prefix, val) VALUES
> ('AX',11),
> ('AX',22),
> ('LZ',33),
> ('AX',44),
> ('LZ',55),
> ('LZ',66);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, CONCAT(prefix, LPAD(num, 5, '0')) AS id 
> FROM test
> ORDER BY id;
> ```
>
> ```
> prefix | num | val | id     
> :----- | --: | --: | :------
> AX     |   1 |  11 | AX00001
> AX     |   2 |  22 | AX00002
> AX     |   3 |  44 | AX00003
> LZ     |   1 |  33 | LZ00001
> LZ     |   2 |  55 | LZ00002
> LZ     |   3 |  66 | LZ00003
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e19fd0c6f8dd4eb43fe9bf944a72bb9)*

Comment: Interesting `auto_increment` behaviour. Thanks for demonstrating it!