# Incrementing Unique IDs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Im having an issue attempting to increment unique ids for a table in MySQL. I have values I would  like to keep as RX##### which I have labeled as a Primary key (prescriptionid).

Is there a way to increment the unique id when a new row is inserted?

```
prescriptionid
RX00001
RX00002
RX00003

CREATE TABLE prescription 
(   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
prescriptionid AS 'RX' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS CHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED, 
.
.
PRIMARY KEY (prescriptionid),
.
.
...);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Comment: Alslo see [generated column (MariaDB)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) / [generated columns MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: You're confusing issues of data retrieval and display with those of data storage. Don't use this as your PK.

Answer (score 0):

You also need `INDEX(Id)` to heep auto_increment happy.

Caveat:  It is possible that a number will be skipped.  If this is not allowed by your business logic, then a different mechanism is needed?