# Creating Custom Automated Serial No in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

The Roll No Format for my dataset is 'AC-1201', 'AC-1202', ........ I want to generate the Roll No automatically. I can find various answers to generate serial no like 1, 2, 3, ...., but, that's not what I need.

I think I have to concatenate AC-12 before every generated serial no or something like that. I'm not able to do it so as I'm a beginner.
[image]

MySQL version 8.0.27. I am using it in the terminal for learning purpose. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Store autoincremented integers 1,2,3 and create your custom number from this value in the query which retrieves the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Comment: What do you of assigning after `AC-1299` ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan My class only has 50 students. So, this situation will never arise and this dataset is just for learning purposes.

Comment: @Indra Ok, I'll try that answer

Comment: @Akina thanks for the solution, but a little bit more elaboration will help me as I have already mentioned, I'm a beginner.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b86289f917298d72dc27afa818aeb59