# FUNCTION does not exist error, trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am having this issue with my newly created database. I created my table and tried adding a prefix when adding data like it is shown in this question [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix) and came up with this trigger to use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_contracts_insert BEFORE INSERT ON contracts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO contracts_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.cid = CONCAT('CN', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_CID(), 5, '0'));
END
```

cid being my primary key to be auto-inserted. I was apparently able to add the trigger  However, when I tried adding my values on the main table, "contracts", with this:

```
INSERT INTO contracts (name, conres, conven, start, end, tipo) VALUES ('Roberto Grajales', 'Pedro', 'Pascual', '2022-12-12', '2022-08-08', 'Servicio');
```

name, conres, conven being VARCHAR type, start and end DATE and tipo being ENUM.
I get the following error message:

```
FUNCTION database.LAST_INSERT_CID does not exist
```

Anyone has any idea why and how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no function LAST_INSERT_CID(). You probably meant [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).