# add a prefix "s_" to an auto incremented id field on a student table, Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Hi i have a table name student like below

```
student(student_id, name, dateofbirth, email, password);
```

the student_id field is auto incremented. I am trying to find an option or way to add a prefix "s_" to my student_id field but I cant seem to. Is it not possible on database application on PHPMyADMIN ??
Thank you.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991148/add-prefix-to-auto-increment-in-mysql-db

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Prefix to auto-increment in mysql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991148/add-prefix-to-auto-increment-in-mysql-db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto increment field can be **ONLY** `integer` of value. Placing an `s_` is not possible.
Either add the prefix in the MySQL query, or use a `view`, or you can use another column instead.