# laravel Autoincrement with prefix

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to laravel framework and i would like to know if there is any way for adding prefix value in auto increment ID

for example
say there are two levels of users Admin and Regular

i want the ID to be stored with prefix values
ADXXX and REXXX

just like giving tag to a user.

Comment: Laravel doesn't have such method [You could try this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991148/add-prefix-to-auto-increment-in-mysql-db)

Comment: @BasheerAhmed thank you.