# how to get receipt num in sequence order like this AB0810001

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

AB is an receipt code should be constant next (**08** todays date) and 10001 is receipt num?

Comment: are you storing the receipt codes in database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Auto Increment Custom Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228408/mysql-auto-increment-custom-values)

Answer (score 1):

```
$prefix      = 'AB';
$today       =  date("d");
$receipt_num = '10001';//from db value

echo $prefix.$today.$receipt_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there always will be 4 characters in front of the receipt number, you could of course use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$data = 'AB0810001';
$receipt = substr($data, 4);
echo $receipt;  // will output 10001
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to get those chunks from that string this should do it:

```
var str = 'AB0810001';
var result = str.match(/([A-Z]{2})(\d{2})(\d{5})/);
result.shift();
console.log(result); //=> ['AB', '08', '10001']
```