# auto increment in Mysql database table with my own choice

Tags: php, mysql

I have following table named oder in mysql database

```
         id    user_id   item_id 
         1       55      5813    
         2       55      359     
         3       56      559  
         4       62      4536    
         5       62      484     
         6       99      4698    
         7       29      435
```

In this table **"id"** is primary key and auto increment on this column is on. Now I want to add a column, it should also be auto incremented and value are like  **OD-001** , **OD-002**. 
Then my table should look like

```
         id    user_id   item_id  order_custom_id
         1       55      5813     OD-001
         2       55      359      OD-002
         3       56      559      OD-003
         4       62      4536     OD-004
         5       62      484      0D-005
         6       99      4698     OD-006
         7       29      435      OD-007
```

**Note:** I am currently working on the PHP Laravel framework. I have go through many questions and articles but nothing worked out for me,

Comment: Add an insert trigger that builds the ID for every inserted record

Comment: where i have to add the trigger , at time of creation ?

Comment: in your mysql server, because trigger will run on every insert operation of that table.

Comment: You can generate custom auto-increment values using stored procedures and a function which always returns the last stored value for custom auto increment field, as described in [Custom Auto Increment Field](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Auto Increment Custom Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228408/mysql-auto-increment-custom-values)

Answer (score 1):

If want to do this by php and you have this table like a Model and your `order_custom_id` always end as your `id` you can use laravel events and create it by getting the last id of your table + 1.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); // Validate the model
    static::creating(function ($your_model) {
        $prev_model = YourModel::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $id = ($prev_model) ? ($prev_model->id +1) : 1;
        $your_model->order_custom_id = sprintf('OD-%s', str_pad($id, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to generate column values based on the auto-increment column values (e.g. 1 -> OD-001).

The first idea that popped into my mind was to use [auto computed columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). Unfortunately, MySQL [does not seem to support this feature.](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78290) (it is related to how the auto-incremented and auto computed column values are generated internally):

> Generated column 'computed_col' cannot refer to auto-increment column.

Another way is to use a trigger to update another column on insert, but personally I avoid triggers if possible, so using a view can be a decent solution:

```
CREATE VIEW orderView AS
SELECT id, user_id, item_id, CONCAT('OD-', LPAD(id, 3, '0')))
FROM order
```

The only disadvantage I see is that values are not persisted and are computed on the fly (more CPU). However, this should work just fine for a fairly small amount of selected rows (< thousands).

NOTE: using a view instead of a separate column also obeys [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (user_id, item_id)
VALUES (20, CONCAT('OD-', LPAD((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id) + 1, 1) FROM table), 3, '0')));
```

This will select the next incremental id from your table, and prepend that to `OD-` with leading zeros.